# Why is my code in C++ so much slower than my code in C

Tags: c++, c

So far, I wrote my code in C (performance is of utmost importance). However, I would like to start writing my algorithms in a generic way. So, I decided to try out C++. I took a simple code in C and translated it into C++ with templates. To my disappointment, the C++ code runs 2.5 times slower. (the C code is compiled with gcc -O3; the C++ code is compiled with g++ -O3)

Am I doing something wrong in C++? Why is there such a performance hit?

Here is the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

static int df_output = 0;
int nCalls = 0;

typedef struct {
  int *pancakes;
  int n;
} STATE;
STATE **solution;

void shuffle(STATE *s) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < s->n; i++) {
    int i1 = rand() % s->n;
    int i2 = rand() % s->n;
    int temp = s->pancakes[i1];
    s->pancakes[i1] = s->pancakes[i2];
    s->pancakes[i2] = temp;
  }
}

STATE *copyState(STATE *s) {
  STATE *res = malloc(sizeof(STATE));
  res->n = s->n;
  res->pancakes = (int *)malloc(res->n * sizeof(int));
  memcpy(res->pancakes, s->pancakes, res->n * sizeof(int));
  return res;
}

// reverse n pancakes
void makeMove(STATE *s, int n) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
    int temp = s->pancakes[i];
    s->pancakes[i] = s->pancakes[n - 1 - i];
    s->pancakes[n - 1 - i]=temp;
  }
}

void printState(STATE *s) {
  int i;
  printf("[");
  for (i = 0; i < s->n; i++) {
    printf("%d", s->pancakes[i]);
    if (i < s->n - 1)
      printf(", ");
  }
  printf("]");
}

int heuristic(STATE *s) {
  int i, res = 0;
  nCalls++;
  for (i = 1; i < s->n; i++)
    if (abs(s->pancakes[i]-s->pancakes[i-1])>1)
      res++;
  if (s->pancakes[0] != 0) res++;
  return res;
}

void tabs(int g) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < g; i++) printf("\t");
}

int df(STATE *s, int g, int left) {
  int h = heuristic(s), i;
  if (g == 0) printf("Thereshold: %d\n", left);
  if (df_output) {
    tabs(g);
    printf("g=%d,left=%d ", g, left); printState(s); printf("\n");}
  if (h == 0) {
    assert(left == 0);
    solution = (STATE **)malloc((g+1) * sizeof(STATE *));
    solution[g] = copyState(s);
    return 1;
  }
  if (left == 0)
    return 0;
  for (i = 2; i <= s->n; i++) {
    makeMove(s, i);
    if (df(s, g+1, left-1)) {
      makeMove(s, i);
      solution[g] = copyState(s);
      return 1;
    }
    makeMove(s, i);
  }
  return 0;
}

void ida(STATE *s) {
  int threshold = 0, i;
  while (!df(s, 0, threshold)) threshold++; 

  for (i = 0; i <= threshold; i++) {
    printf("%d. ", i);
    printState(solution[i]);
    printf("\n");
    //if (i < threshold - 1) printf("->");
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  STATE *s = (STATE *)malloc(sizeof(STATE));
  int i, n;
  int myInstance[] = {0,5,4,7,2,6,1,3};
  s->n = 8;
  s->pancakes = myInstance;
  printState(s); printf("\n");
  ida(s);
  printf("%d calls to heuristic()", nCalls);
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "assert.h"
using namespace std;

static int df_output = 0;
int nCalls = 0;

class PancakeState {
public:
  int *pancakes;
  int n;
  PancakeState *copyState();
  void printState();
};

PancakeState *PancakeState::copyState() {
  PancakeState *res = new PancakeState();
  res->n = this->n;
  res->pancakes = (int *)malloc(this->n * sizeof(int));
  memcpy(res->pancakes, this->pancakes, 
     this->n * sizeof(int));
  return res;
}

void PancakeState::printState() {
  int i;
  cout << "[";
  for (i = 0; i < this->n; i++) {
    cout << this->pancakes[i];
    if (i < this->n - 1)
      cout << ", ";
  }
  cout << "]";
}

class PancakeMove {
public:
  PancakeMove(int n) {this->n = n;}
  int n;
};

class Pancake {
public:
  int heuristic (PancakeState &);
  int bf(PancakeState &);
  PancakeMove *getMove(int);
  void makeMove(PancakeState &, PancakeMove &);
  void unmakeMove(PancakeState &, PancakeMove &);
};

int Pancake::bf(PancakeState &s) {
  return s.n - 1;
}

PancakeMove *Pancake::getMove(int i) {
  return new PancakeMove(i + 2); 
}

// reverse n pancakes
void Pancake::makeMove(PancakeState &s, PancakeMove &m) {
  int i;
  int n = m.n;
  for (i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
    int temp = s.pancakes[i];
    s.pancakes[i] = s.pancakes[n - 1 - i];
    s.pancakes[n - 1 - i]=temp;
  }
}

void Pancake::unmakeMove(PancakeState &state, PancakeMove &move) {
  makeMove(state, move);
}

int Pancake::heuristic(PancakeState &s) {
  int i, res = 0;
  nCalls++;
  for (i = 1; i < s.n; i++)
    if (abs(s.pancakes[i]-s.pancakes[i-1])>1)
      res++;
  if (s.pancakes[0] != 0) res++;
  return res;
}

void tabs(int g) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < g; i++) cout << "\t";
}

template <class Domain, class State, class Move>
class Alg {
public:
  State **solution;
  int threshold;
  bool verbose;
  int df(Domain &d, State &s, int g);
  void ida(Domain &d, State &s);
};

template <class Domain, class State, class Move>
int Alg<Domain, State, Move>::df(Domain &d, State &s, int g) {
  int h = d.heuristic(s), i;
  if (g == 0) 
    cout << "Thereshold:" << this->threshold << "\n";
  if (this->verbose) {
    tabs(g);
    cout << "g=" << g;
    s.printState(); cout << "\n";
  }
  if (h == 0) {
    solution = (State **)malloc((g+1) * sizeof(State *));
    solution[g] = s.copyState();
    return 1;
  }
  if (g == this->threshold)
    return 0;
  for (i = 0; i < d.bf(s); i++) {
    Move *move = d.getMove(i);
    d.makeMove(s, *move);
    if (this->df(d, s, g+1)) {
      d.unmakeMove(s, *move);
      solution[g] = s.copyState();
      delete move;
      return 1;
    }
    d.unmakeMove(s, *move);
    delete move;
  }
  return 0;
}

template <class Domain, class State, class Move>
void Alg<Domain, State, Move>::ida(Domain &d, State &s) {
  int i;
  this->threshold = 0;
  while (!this->df(d, s, 0)) threshold++; 

  for (i = 0; i <= threshold; i++) {
    cout << i << ".";
    this->solution[i]->printState();
    cout << "\n";
    //if (i < threshold - 1) printf("->");
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Pancake *d = new Pancake();
  PancakeState *s = new PancakeState();
  int myInstance[] = {0,5,4,7,2,6,1,3};
  s->pancakes = myInstance;
  s->n = 8;
  s->printState(); cout << "\n";
  Alg<Pancake, PancakeState, PancakeMove> *alg = new Alg<Pancake, PancakeState, PancakeMove>();
  //alg->verbose = true;
  alg->ida(*d, *s);
  cout << nCalls < "calls to heuristic()";
  delete alg;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: We're not going to trawl through hundreds of lines of code.  Try using a profiler to identify specific bottlenecks, and then create reduced code examples based on just those.

Comment: Did you try RAAI (stack based allocation) instead of _homebrew_ `new()`/`delete` memory management already?

Comment: What compiler, and what compiler settings? For example MS Visual C++ will do a lot of checking in places where C code doesnt (string/vector indices for example).

Comment: its only barely C++. For example PancakeState should be vector<int>

Comment: What exactly have you measured? How did you measure it? What are the absolute times?

Comment: It does not look like a direct transcription from C. It seems to me that there are plenty of classes while there was only one struct in your original code.

Comment: I have re-posted this question in a form that does not require looking at the code (and got criticized for duplicating the question). With these two posts, I got banned from asking any more questions... Please consider my case and remove the ban.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of malloc() and operator new calls in there.  Stop doing that, and performance will improve.  And don't use malloc() in C++, use operator new always.

For example, PancakeMove is a small, trivial struct.  But you allocate instances of it dynamically, which is slow.  Just pass it around by value.

Comment: 3 times as many new's and only 2.5 times slower.  Truth is you have no idea which one is faster.  The amount of work being done here is so minute that it is impossible to accurately profile.  When you want to time something you should run it in a loop for several minutes then devide the total time by the number of iterations.  IE: start the timer, run 10,000 iterations, stop the timer, devide delta time by 10,000.  Do the same for both code paths then compare results.

Comment: Passing moves by value did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you are allocating a lot of small things on the heap instead of on the stack. That's pretty "expensive", so will take extra time.

This code (which is modified from your original code) runs within 1ms of the C code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

static int df_output = 0;
int nCalls = 0;

class PancakeState {
public:
    PancakeState(int n) : n(n), pancakes(n) 
    {
    }
    PancakeState(int n, int *v) : n(n), pancakes(n) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        pancakes[i] = v[i];
    }
    PancakeState(): n(0) {}
public:
    vector<int> pancakes;
    int n;
    PancakeState *copyState();
    void printState();
};

void PancakeState::printState() {
  int i;
  cout << "[";
  for (i = 0; i < this->n; i++) {
    cout << this->pancakes[i];
    if (i < this->n - 1)
      cout << ", ";
  }
  cout << "]";
}

class PancakeMove {
public:
    PancakeMove(int n) : n(n)  {}
    int n;
};

class Pancake {
public:
  int heuristic (PancakeState &);
  int bf(PancakeState&);
  PancakeMove getMove(int);
  void makeMove(PancakeState &, PancakeMove &);
  void unmakeMove(PancakeState &, PancakeMove &);
};

int Pancake::bf(PancakeState& s) {
  return s.n - 1;
}

PancakeMove Pancake::getMove(int i) {
  return PancakeMove(i + 2); 
}

// reverse n pancakes
void Pancake::makeMove(PancakeState &s, PancakeMove &m) {
  int i;
  int n = m.n;
  for (i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
    int temp = s.pancakes[i];
    s.pancakes[i] = s.pancakes[n - 1 - i];
    s.pancakes[n - 1 - i]=temp;
  }
}

void Pancake::unmakeMove(PancakeState &state, PancakeMove &move) {
  makeMove(state, move);
}

int Pancake::heuristic(PancakeState &s) {
  int i, res = 0;
  nCalls++;
  for (i = 1; i < s.n; i++)
    if (abs(s.pancakes[i]-s.pancakes[i-1])>1)
      res++;
  if (s.pancakes[0] != 0) res++;
  return res;
}

void tabs(int g) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < g; i++) cout << "\t";
}

template <class Domain, class State, class Move>
class Alg {
public:
  vector<State> solution;
  int threshold;
  bool verbose;
  int df(Domain &d, State &s, int g);
  void ida(Domain &d, State &s);
};

template <class Domain, class State, class Move>
int Alg<Domain, State, Move>::df(Domain &d, State &s, int g) {
  int h = d.heuristic(s), i;
  if (g == 0) 
    cout << "Thereshold:" << threshold << "\n";
  if (this->verbose) {
    tabs(g);
    cout << "g=" << g;
    s.printState(); cout << "\n";
  }
  if (h == 0) {
      solution.resize(g+1);
      solution[g] = s;
      return 1;
  }
  if (g == this->threshold)
    return 0;
  for (i = 0; i < d.bf(s); i++) {
    Move move = d.getMove(i);
    d.makeMove(s, move);
    if (this->df(d, s, g+1)) {
      d.unmakeMove(s, move);
      solution[g] = s;
      return 1;
    }
    d.unmakeMove(s, move);
  }
  return 0;
}

template <class Domain, class State, class Move>
void Alg<Domain, State, Move>::ida(Domain &d, State &s) {
  int i;
  this->threshold = 0;
  while (!this->df(d, s, 0)) threshold++; 

  for (i = 0; i <= threshold; i++) {
    cout << i << ".";
    solution[i].printState();
    cout << "\n";
    //if (i < threshold - 1) printf("->");
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Pancake d = Pancake();
  int myInstance[] = {0,5,4,7,2,6,1,3};
  PancakeState s(8, myInstance);
  s.printState(); cout << "\n";
  Alg<Pancake, PancakeState, PancakeMove> *alg = new Alg<Pancake, PancakeState, PancakeMove>();
  //alg->verbose = true;
  alg->ida(d, s);
  cout << nCalls < "calls to heuristic()";
  delete alg;
  return 0;
}
```

As an extra benefit of not making so many direct allocations, it also doesn't leak 22 lumps of memory throughout the execution, which is quite a useful feature.

(If you want to see what changed, here's a diff - ignoring whitespace only changes):

```
--- pcake.orig.cpp  2014-04-13 15:43:24.861417827 +0100
+++ pcake.cpp   2014-04-13 15:42:25.145165372 +0100
@@ -1,7 +1,9 @@
 #include <iostream>
-#include "stdlib.h"
-#include "string.h"
-#include "assert.h"
+#include <stdlib.h>
+#include <string.h>
+#include <assert.h>
+#include <vector>
+
 using namespace std;

 static int df_output = 0;
@@ -9,21 +11,22 @@

 class PancakeState {
 public:
-  int *pancakes;
+    PancakeState(int n) : n(n), pancakes(n) 
+   {
+   }
+    PancakeState(int n, int *v) : n(n), pancakes(n) 
+   {
+       for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
+       pancakes[i] = v[i];
+   }
+    PancakeState(): n(0) {}
+public:
+    vector<int> pancakes;
   int n;
   PancakeState *copyState();
   void printState();
 };

-PancakeState *PancakeState::copyState() {
-  PancakeState *res = new PancakeState();
-  res->n = this->n;
-  res->pancakes = (int *)malloc(this->n * sizeof(int));
-  memcpy(res->pancakes, this->pancakes, 
-     this->n * sizeof(int));
-  return res;
-}
-
 void PancakeState::printState() {
   int i;
   cout << "[";
@@ -37,25 +40,25 @@

 class PancakeMove {
 public:
-  PancakeMove(int n) {this->n = n;}
+    PancakeMove(int n) : n(n)  {}
   int n;
 };

 class Pancake {
 public:
   int heuristic (PancakeState &);
-  int bf(PancakeState &);
-  PancakeMove *getMove(int);
+  int bf(PancakeState&);
+  PancakeMove getMove(int);
   void makeMove(PancakeState &, PancakeMove &);
   void unmakeMove(PancakeState &, PancakeMove &);
 };

-int Pancake::bf(PancakeState &s) {
+int Pancake::bf(PancakeState& s) {
   return s.n - 1;
 }

-PancakeMove *Pancake::getMove(int i) {
-  return new PancakeMove(i + 2); 
+PancakeMove Pancake::getMove(int i) {
+  return PancakeMove(i + 2); 
 }

 // reverse n pancakes
@@ -91,7 +94,7 @@
 template <class Domain, class State, class Move>
 class Alg {
 public:
-  State **solution;
+  vector<State> solution;
   int threshold;
   bool verbose;
   int df(Domain &d, State &s, int g);
@@ -102,30 +105,28 @@
 int Alg<Domain, State, Move>::df(Domain &d, State &s, int g) {
   int h = d.heuristic(s), i;
   if (g == 0) 
-    cout << "Thereshold:" << this->threshold << "\n";
+    cout << "Thereshold:" << threshold << "\n";
   if (this->verbose) {
     tabs(g);
     cout << "g=" << g;
     s.printState(); cout << "\n";
   }
   if (h == 0) {
-    solution = (State **)malloc((g+1) * sizeof(State *));
-    solution[g] = s.copyState();
+      solution.resize(g+1);
+      solution[g] = s;
     return 1;
   }
   if (g == this->threshold)
     return 0;
   for (i = 0; i < d.bf(s); i++) {
-    Move *move = d.getMove(i);
-    d.makeMove(s, *move);
+    Move move = d.getMove(i);
+    d.makeMove(s, move);
     if (this->df(d, s, g+1)) {
-      d.unmakeMove(s, *move);
-      solution[g] = s.copyState();
-      delete move;
+      d.unmakeMove(s, move);
+      solution[g] = s;
       return 1;
     }
-    d.unmakeMove(s, *move);
-    delete move;
+    d.unmakeMove(s, move);
   }
   return 0;
 }
@@ -138,23 +139,22 @@

   for (i = 0; i <= threshold; i++) {
     cout << i << ".";
-    this->solution[i]->printState();
+    solution[i].printState();
     cout << "\n";
     //if (i < threshold - 1) printf("->");
   }
 }

 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
-  Pancake *d = new Pancake();
-  PancakeState *s = new PancakeState();
+  Pancake d = Pancake();
   int myInstance[] = {0,5,4,7,2,6,1,3};
-  s->pancakes = myInstance;
-  s->n = 8;
-  s->printState(); cout << "\n";
+  PancakeState s(8, myInstance);
+  s.printState(); cout << "\n";
   Alg<Pancake, PancakeState, PancakeMove> *alg = new Alg<Pancake, PancakeState, PancakeMove>();
   //alg->verbose = true;
-  alg->ida(*d, *s);
+  alg->ida(d, s);
   cout << nCalls < "calls to heuristic()";
   delete alg;
   return 0;
 }
+
```